# Loess prediction for many groups of data

Tags: r, predict, loess

I'm using `loess` to interpolate data between measurement dates from individual plots.  I would like to get daily resolution for all 48 plots in each year.  Below is a sample from my dataset:

```
dput(vi.sample)
```

structure(list(year = c(2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 
2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 
2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L), julian = c(150L, 
153L, 157L, 165L, 173L, 179L, 186L, 193L, 201L, 208L, 226L, 150L, 
153L, 157L, 165L, 173L, 179L, 186L, 193L, 201L, 208L, 226L), 
    jdx = c(2.573770492, 2.625245902, 2.693879781, 2.831147541, 
    2.968415301, 3.07136612, 3.19147541, 3.311584699, 3.448852459, 
    3.568961749, 3.877814208, 2.573770492, 2.625245902, 2.693879781, 
    2.831147541, 2.968415301, 3.07136612, 3.19147541, 3.311584699, 
    3.448852459, 3.568961749, 3.877814208), site = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "east", class = "factor"), 
    type = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "b", class = "factor"), 
    trt = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "a", class = "factor"), 
    plot = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), vi = c(0.41, 0.44, 
    0.52, 0.64, 0.66, 0.67, 0.64, 0.66, 0.61, 0.7, 0.7, 0.41, 
    0.45, 0.55, 0.61, 0.63, 0.66, 0.63, 0.64, 0.6, 0.7, 0.69)), .Names = c("year", 
"julian", "jdx", "site", "type", "trt", "plot", "vi"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-22L))

I need to interpolate the data from each plot within each of three seasons (2012 - 2014) of data collected.  I have successfully done so by using the `subset` function. Note that I am using julian dates, however I'm not particularly wedded to this date format.

```
lo <- loess(vi~julian, 
               subset(vi.sample, year=="2012" & site=="east" 
               & type=="b" & trt=="a" & plot=="1"),
               model=TRUE,
               na.action=na.exclude)
```

**Question**: Is there a way to automate the code to interpolate data from each plot/year combination without having to subset each one?  I'm thinking along the lines of the `nlsList` function using the `| year/site/type/trt/plot` design.

My second question deals with the `predict` function.  The following code successfully displays the fitted vi values for the plot specified above.

```
pred <- predict(lo, seq(from =150, to =226, 
            by = 1), se=FALSE)
```

However, the corresponding x-values are not the same as the original julian dates.
**Question**: How do I get the predicted values to represent the julian dates used in the loess model?  Note that these dates may differ for each year/plot.

Answer (score 1):

For question 1, this is a standard data manipulation - split, apply, combine.
Here using `plyr`

```
library(plyr)
fits <- dlply(vi.sample, .(year, site, type, trt, plot), .fun=function(samp)
    loess(vi ~ julian, model=T, na.action=na.exclude, data=samp))
```

You split the data into groups by year/site/type/trt/plot, apply the loess function, then combine the results back into a list.

For the second question, you choose the julian dates when you do the prediction, maybe I am missing something there.

Comment: thanks for your answer.  A follow-up: `fits` generates a large list that can't be coerced into a data frame.  I've tried `unlist` but get the error: `incorrect number of dimensions`.  Any pointers on converting this into a dataframe?